# Cannot find com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable class

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, account-kit

My build.gradle is:

```
// for facebook account kit
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'

// for google firebase database
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'

// for google firebase cloud messaging
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
```

After rebuild project，a error happens.

Error:(74, 27) error: Cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
Cannot find 
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable class

==============================================

Resolution:

The reason is that after rebuilding the project, gradle download the latest version of "account-kit-sdk" to 4.25.0, the new version changes some about gms, so make some conflicts with firebase messaging,

So I downgrade the account-kit-sdk version, change import version from "account-kit-sdk:4.+" to "account-kit-sdk:4.24.0"

Then the issue has been resolved.

But I think it is not the best resolution about this problem.

Welcome friends add some new ways to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Version 4.25.0 of `com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk` has a dependency on `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.0.1` that is not present in version 4.24.0.  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone` adds many transitive dependencies on other `com.google.android.gms` modules, including `base`, `basement`, `tasks`, `auth`, and `auth-base`.

The Firebase libraries also have transitive dependencies on numerous `com.google.android.gms` modules.  If the version numbers of all of the Firebase and Play Services modules in a build are not the same, problems such as this one occur.

A simple solution is to use version 11.0.1 of all Firebase and Play Services libraries you list in your gradle dependencies:

```
// for google firebase database
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'

// for google firebase cloud messaging
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
```

You should also specify a fixed version number for the Facebook library to make your build predictable and repeatable:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.25.0'
```

The risk of specifying the version as "4.+" is that when a new version is released that has transitive dependencies on a new version of the Play Services libraries, the new Facebook lib version will be automatically used and your build will break again.

To debug problems like this one, you can open the Gradle window in Android Studio and double-click on *:app -> Tasks -> android -> androidDependencies* to generate a dependency tree. The tree can then be examined to find version mismatches.